Should one construct a “pursuit” of life through philosophical reasoning?
Should one first construct a systematic understanding of our senses and the world, and then determine a “pursuit” of life (for example, the cumulative feeling of happiness, achieving immortality, or ending one’s life as soon as possible) through careful reasoning? Or, alternatively, should one determine a pursuit without much thought? Or should one simply follow their heart, perhaps with a flexible or even undefined pursuit?
I understand the “should” here is vague, as there may be no values that could determine a clear preference. I’m interested in exploring the potential consequences of each approach and any critiques of the question itself.

"should one" is a personal judgement based on the individual case...

The first approach is simply not feasible because "systematic understanding" is not a fixed state that can be achieved. Understanding is part of an ongoing evolution, and it is unavoidable; it cannot be resisted through conscious choice because human consciousness has no limits. At different points in life, you might follow a structured approach that seems effective, but sooner or later, you may find yourself abandoning it and moving on to a new one. This cycle may continue indefinitely until we realize (if ever) that we are trying to formulate methods to live as if life were a problem to solve, rather than simply living it.
This tendency arises from our excessive emphasis on knowledge, which we often mistake for understanding. When understanding is put into words through thought, it transforms into knowledge. This suggests that true understanding, or clarity, exists before thought—a spontaneous clarity without any gap between understanding and action. When there is no gap, there is no conflict, which addresses the second part of your question. Whatever action you take in the world, avoid inner conflict; it’s not a matter of right or wrong, or of "should" or "should not."
If you are sufficiently aware and act consciously without inner conflict, questions of right or wrong, or of ethical and non-ethical, dissolve in the moment of action. Therefore, it’s not about whether you should "follow your heart" but about acting with awareness, free from self-conflict."Most importantly, life is not something we pursue; it is something we live, occurring in every moment—just like death, which isn’t a distant event but a gradual process happening continuously, as we are already dying bit by bit with each passing moment."

A systematic understanding doesn't have to stay fixed. It can be adjusted as time passes. The emphasis is whether to construct a systematic understanding at all to determine what one hopes to achieve or pursue in life.
